# Delaunay Algorithm form scipy.spatial

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, spatial, delaunay

I looked a lot on the internet but I couldn't find the `Delaunay` source file which used in python from `scipy.spatial`
I will be happy if anyone can give me the source file for this algorithm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
In [121]: spatial.Delaunay??
Init signature: spatial.Delaunay(points, furthest_site=False, incremental=False, qhull_options=None)
File:           /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/scipy/spatial/qhull.cpython-35m-i386-linux-gnu.so
Type:           type
```

The github directory has a

```
scipy/scipy/spatial/qhull.pyx
scipy/scipy/spatial/qhull/
```

So it's a Cython wrapper around the https://github.com/qhull/qhull package.